How to open and use NPZ files to DICOM files
a few months ago I was granted permission to download and use the RAD-ChestCT dataset from https://zenodo.org/doi/10.5281/zenodo.6406113 and it was in a numpy compressed 3D numpy array (npz format) files. I intended to use it as data training for the thesis research I'm currently doing, if anyone has/had experience using the dataset or any knowledge in 3d numpy can you help me answer these few questions I have, my questions are how do I use it and how do I convert it back to Pydicom?
since in my thesis research I also use dicom ct-scan from the hospitals as the testing and validation data and I intended to uniform the file format into one format, which is dicom, for the sake of simplicity and easy to use.
I'm currently still looking up for a way to change these npz files into nifti format in hopes that it works

npz whether compressed or not, is a zip archive. So it may contain more than one array. See np.load and np.savez docs to learn how to read them. See Pydicom docs for how to convert arrays and save the result.
